XAML Binding Failures for Name and Price in a Maui ListView Selection
I have two lists, in the left list i load Drinks and when i select them it adds it to the right.
It works perfectly fine but i get two XAML binding failures on the Name and Price of the item.
This is my Left List Handler:
private void OnLeftItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        Getraenk? selectedGetraenk = e.SelectedItem as Getraenk;
        if (selectedGetraenk != null)
        {
            RightListItems.Add(selectedGetraenk);

            ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
        }
    }
    
}

And this is my
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Medium" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Preis, StringFormat='Preis: {0:C}'}" FontSize="Small" />
</StackLayout>

Everything is correctly binded and there are no Typos!
I debbugged and cant figure it out why. Maybe its something on Maui?

but i get two XAML binding failures on the Name and Price of the item Can you elaborate on your problem? What‘s the binding failures? Besides, could you please post more code snippets here so that we can help you better?
